# Is there a limit to the number of weapons you can carry?

Tags: hyrule-warriors

In getting an awful lot of swords. Is there a limit to how many of the same weapon I can end up having?  If so, what is the max and what happens if I get another one?

The only way I've seen to get rid of weapons is to put abilities into empty slots using the smith. Is there another way to trim down my weapon inventory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're allowed to keep ten pieces of each weapon type (e.g. the Knight Sword). If you obtain an eleventh or even twelfth one during a battle, you'll be asked to throw some of them away till you're down to ten or less (you'll get rupees for the dropped ones).

Comment: The game seems to mostly have a tutorial style of "don't say anything until it's relevant" which I rather like.